# Magento 2 Checkout Billing Address Before Shipping Address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2.3.5

What we would like to accomplish is the have the Shipping Address where Magento 2 has the Billing address and viceversa, where the checkbox saying that: "my billing address is the same as shipping" would be "my shipping address is the same as billing" (And the billing address is the first thing that the customer fills inside the checkout).

I've tryed contacting various companies too, most of them said that is not a simple thing because the shipping address has it is has been hard coded in Magento 2.

Have anyone any Idea how i could accomplish this result?

Comment: What about shipping method?

Comment: Shipping method should replace the billing address position, we would like to reverse the logic behind the addresses